# silence warnings in individual jupyter cell running R kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

One of the cells in my jupyterlab (v3.5.3) notebook produces thousands of warning messages when it executes a certain function from an r-library I'm using. All of these warnings are useless, so I want to disable their printing.  However, most other cells produce warnings that I might want to see.  How do I selectively disable certain cells from displaying warning messages?

An R-based solution is fine, but if there is a unified way to accomplish this in python notebooks too, that would be nice.